# Getting correct Total Row count and Row Numbers for Pagination

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, pdo

Now I have done this easily with PDO and SQL server however I am struggling getting this working correctly for any general Query. Since I do want this to be reusable by our MySQL tables over any project I am turning here for help.

So the way I used it for PDO and SQL server

```
function pagedQuery($dbh,$q,$sort,$offset,$limit,$params = array()) {
    $limit = preg_replace("/[^0-9]]/","",$limit);
    $offset = preg_replace("/[^0-9]]/","",$offset);
    $q = preg_replace("/^[^\w]*SELECT/i","SELECT COUNT(*) OVER() as num_rows, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY $sort) AS rownum,",$q);
    $q = "SELECT * FROM (".$q.") as pagingTable WHERE rownum > $offset AND rownum <= ($offset+$limit)";

    ## Prepare Query
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare($q);

    try {
        $stmt->execute($params);
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        print $e->getMessage();
    }

    ## Return Results
    return $stmt->fetchAll();
```

Now obviously the OVER functionality does not exist and MySQL and this has to be modified. Here is my attempt at a new version:

```
function mysqlPagedQuery($dbh,$q,$table,$sort,$offset,$limit,$params = array()) {
    $limit = preg_replace("/[^0-9]]/","",$limit);
    $offset = preg_replace("/[^0-9]]/","",$offset);
    $q = preg_replace("/^[^\w]*SELECT/i","SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) as num_rows FROM ".$table.") AS num_rows, @rowN := @rowN + 1 AS rownum,",$q);
    $q = "SELECT * FROM (".$q.") as pagingTable WHERE rownum > $offset AND rownum <= ($offset+$limit)";

    ## Prepare Query
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare($q);

    try {
        $query = $dbh->query("set @rowN = 0;");
        $stmt->execute($params);
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        print $e->getMessage();
    }

    ## Return Results
    return $stmt->fetchAll();
```

Now this will "work" given that you give it a table but I soon realized that the num_rows will not return the correct value unless given all of the WHERE clause of the query sent into it. I would have to parse that in an inefficient manner and I feel there is a much easier way to do this than I am making it out to be.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using PDO you should be using [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) with placeholder values and supply any user data as separate arguments. In this code you have potentially severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Never use string interpolation or concatenation and instead use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and never put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly in your query. Refer to [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) for guidance with this and other problems.

Comment: Not sure if I'm reading this correctly. Are you converting something for Microsoft SQL Server to something for MySQL?

Comment: Maybe look into Limit and Offset. [like this maybe](http://www.petefreitag.com/item/451.cfm)

Comment: bobkingof12vs helped me out with this one with the post he linked. @tadman I have read PHP the Right Way and I understand the right way to do this. This was old code I did not write and the queries are being prepared? Let me know how my posted answer is not using the method described. No user is getting to this function, the developers are the only ones running queries through this that are prepared before they get to this function as well.

Comment: Preparing statements is half the battle. The other half is using placeholder values, which you avoid doing here. It doesn't matter if it's for developers only, or not on the internet, because that's just today's situation and these things have a habit of changing without you realizing. Don't set yourself up for disaster. Doing it right is easier than all this junk with `preg_replace`. You're actually going out of your way to complicate things.

Comment: @tadman Ok thanks I will go back and fix this then. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with this thanks to bobkingof12vs posted link. Can't give answer credit to him directly because it was not posted here :(

```
function mysqlPagedQuery($dbh,$q,$sort,$offset,$limit,$params = array()){


$limit = preg_replace("/[^0-9]]/","",$limit);
$offset = preg_replace("/[^0-9]]/","",$offset);
//need to use the original query a few times to create paged 
$tempQuery = $q;
//replaces query's select with a count to get numrows
$q1 = "SELECT sql_calc_found_rows * FROM (".$tempQuery.") AS tempTable";
## Prepare Query
$stmt1 = $dbh->prepare($q1);

$q2 = preg_replace("/^[^\w]*SELECT/i","SELECT FOUND_ROWS() as num_rows,",$tempQuery);
$q2 .= " ORDER BY ".$sort;
$q2 .= " LIMIT ".$offset.",".$limit;
//print $q2;
## Prepare Query
$stmt2 = $dbh->prepare($q2);

try{
    $stmt1->execute();
    $stmt2->execute($params);

}
catch(PDOException $e){
    print $e->getMessage();
}

## Return Results
return $stmt2->fetchAll();
```

}